# Parameter dependent change of variable and MLE

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

Say we are making maximum likelihood estimation of parameter $\theta$ observed data $y_1,\dots,y_n$ which are iid, a known density $f_X(\cdot; \theta)$ where $X_i = g(Y_i)$ where $g$ is a bijektiv monotone increasing or decreasing function. In this case, we can apply the change of variable to get

$$ f_Y (y;\theta) = f_X(g(y);\theta)\vert g'(y)\vert $$

which we can use to find the MLE of $\theta$. **However, is this still a valid procedure if $g$ also depends on $\theta$** such that we are maximizing

$$ f_Y (y;\theta) = f_X(g(y;\theta);\theta)\vert g'(y;\theta)\vert $$

where $g(\cdot;\theta)$ is a monotone increasing or decreasing function for all values $\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is valid by the definition of [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables).

For example, suppose that $y_i \sim N(\mu,1)$ and $x_i = g(y_i;\mu) = y_i-\mu \sim N(0,1)$, and therefore you cannot estimate this parameter. The problem is that you are transforming the variable based on a transformation that you do not know.

Comment: Though this just happen because we substract exactly mu but would work if it was 1/2 mu that we substract then we can estimate mu. Are there a formal restriction on f and g that state whether or not we will be able to find an MLE?